# `absolute` elements is relative to a `backdrop-filter` parent

Tags: html, css

[image]

If `backdrop-filter: blur` is applied to the `box 2` element, `absolute element` will be relative to `box 2`, rather than the green-bordered element which has `relative` positioning.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/sheey11/pen/XWGqEaw

Is this a bug? I have looked up MDN but can't find any docs that suggests `backdrop-filter` will have an effect on positioning.